# Rewrite Rule /index.html -> /some-pretty-description

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Basically I have:

*www.myfancysiteicantcodemyself.com/index.html*

with a rewrite rule so it becomes

*www.myfancysiteicantcodemyself.com*

But what I would really like is this:

*www.myfancysiteicantcodemyself.com/index.html
-> www.myfancysiteicantcodemyself.com/some-cool-words-for-indexpage

www.myfancysiteicantcodemyself.com/anotherpageA.html
-> www.myfancysiteicantcodemyself.com/some-cool-words-for-pageA*

etc.…

How do I achieve this please, without moving files and creating a 301 and google evaluating me from scratch?

PS:
atm my htaccess loks like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.(html?|php)\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^index\.(html?|php)$ http://www.example.com/ [R=301,L]
ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
Header unset ETag
FileETag None
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresDefault "access plus 10 years"
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .html .htm
```

Answer (score 0):

You *need* to do a 301, since google will still try to go to `/index.html` and `/anotherpageA.html`, and you'll need to 301 redirect to tell search engines that the content has moved.

So, the easiest way to do this is actually rename your files and use a 301. Otherwise, you're going to have to both do a 301 redirect as well as an internal rewrite.

For example:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.(html?|php)\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^index\.(html?|php)$ http://www.example.com/some-cool-words-for-indexpage [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^some-cool-words-for-indexpage$ /index.html [L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /anotherpageA.html\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^ http://www.example.com/some-cool-words-for-pageA [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^some-cool-words-for-pageA$ /anotherpageA.html [L]
```

etc...